# Add optional params to methods in a trait scala

Tags: scala, playframework

I have a trait with a method that's being used by 3 different classes, in one of the classes, I would like to override the method to accept an additional param, is this possible? how would one go about this in scala?

PS: I am new to Scala

Desired example:

```
trait Iterator {
    def hasNext(a : String): 
}
class Iterator extends Iterator {
   override def hasNext(a : String, b: String) = {
     ...
   }
}
```

Comment: Not by overriding, first off, you can only override methods when you extend a class or a trait (or mix in traits), when you say you `use` a trait, first thing that comes to mind is you pass it as a dependency. Overriding keeps the signature of the function the as the same as the super class. so if you really want to add that extra field, add it to the trait as an optional and by-name value, like: `def whatever(..., other: => Option[TypeYouWant]): TheSameReturnType = ...`

Comment: Thanks for the response @AminMal, I am extending the trait, that's why I am overriding

Comment: no problem, so just stick to the second approach. use by-name to avoid additional computations when you do not want to use that optional parameter. you can also add e default value of None for better api usage. there is also another approach which is overloading, 2 methods with the same name, but different signatures, but I don't think this is what you're looking for.

Comment: @AminMal the optional param did not work for me but the overloading approach has worked, thank you so much.